# How to catch a RLMException in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm using Realm in my iOS app written in Swift. Since you inevitable run in RLMException, which causes your app to crash, I just wanted to know how to catch or report fatal errors like this (those are probably triggered by some objC code):

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object has been deleted or invalidated.'
>       *** First throw call stack:"

Comment: You cannot "catch" an exception in Swift 1.2 or before. It is fatal. Update to Swift 2.0 if you want to be able to catch exceptions. And even then I don't think you're going to catch _this_ exception.

Comment: The previous comment is wrong. The exception referenced in the question is not a Swift 2.0 exception, but rather an Objective-C exception. Like many cocoa frameworks, Realm throws Objective-C exceptions when its API is being misused and those exceptions generally mean you should rewrite your code so they do not happen. They are not meant to be handled at runtime. In your case, you should check if your object is invalidated before attempting to access that object.